# Is there a way to change the device camera FOV with ARFoundation Face Tracking (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, ar-foundation

While developing a face filter app in Unity, we faced challenges with the device camera's default field of view (FOV), which appeared overly zoomed in, limiting the user's zooming capabilities within the app. Our goal was to enable a customizable camera FOV, allowing seamless zoom adjustments for a more natural experience.

Efforts to integrate the XR Origin camera feed into a UI RawImage using RenderTexture led to the AR face filter not appearing on the RawImage feed. Attempts to address this involved adding a Parent GameObject to the "Camera Offset" GameObject. However, adjusting its position only affected the FaceFilter's position on the human face, and scaling the Parent GameObject altered the FaceFilter's size undesirably.

Exploring access to the iOS native camera FOV didn't yield the desired zoom effects. Unfortunately, these attempts didn't achieve our goal of adjusting the camera's FOV without impacting the FaceFilter's scale or other AR Foundation subsystems.

Comment: Assuming you are talking about a webcamera or mobile camera. Field of view is only adjustable if there is optical zoom, and that is rare for that type of cameras. "Zooming" is typically done by scaling up a part of the produced image. Is the problem that you only get access to clipped image from the camera?

Comment: @JonasH Yes, it's the mobile camera for iOS and Android using ARFoundation. I've managed to get the "Zooming" done by scaling up a part of the produced image from the "XRCpuImage". However, after doing that the GameObjects won't be rendered and shown on the "rawImage.texture = xrCpuTexture".